# @transactional in spring and hibernate integration

Tags: spring, hibernate

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread.

Getting this error even after adding @Transactional to Service Class.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"><property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /></bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

@Service
@Transactional
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService {

    @Autowired
    private CommonDao commonDao;

    public List<FModel> getAll() {
        return commonDao.getAll();
    }

}


@Repository
public class CommonDaoImpl implements CommonDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<FModel> getAll() {
        List<FModel> list = new ArrayList<FModel>();
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from FModel");
        list = query.list();
        return list;
    }
}
```

This is hibernate configuration.

```
<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> --> <!-- This is for JTA -->
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.models" />
```

Comment: Pls show your stacktrace and your java class using @transactional

Comment: Service and Dao added

Comment: Show your hibernate configuration.

Comment: Then the only thing I can imagine is that you have multiple configuration files loaded by both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` which both do component-scanning and scanning the same packages and thus beans.